# Migrate existing Room database from :app to :databaseModule

Tags: android, database, migration, android-room, modularity

Working on an app that suffered the downfall of becoming a monolith, thus crippling code maintenance.

Currently the focus has been on improving multiple aspects of the app code, and one of them is to make the app modular (combination of feature and layers).

This process is complete, but there is a need to migrate any existing database data from previous versions when the user installs this new one and I am unable to find a guide/documentation for this.

How can I migrate an existing Room database data from one module to another module so when users install this new version over the older one they do not lose existing information?

Comment: I think you just have to move the code base to different module

Answer (score 1):

Databases are by default stored in a single place (`data/data/<the_package_name>/databases/<the_database_filename>`) so the module is irrelevant.

So it's just a matter of doing the migration. In short I'd suggest

1. Create the modified @Entity annotated classes.
2. Compile the project.
3. Look in Android Studio's Android View for java(generated) and find the class that is the same name as the @Database class but suffixed with **_Impl**. In that class there will be a method named createAllTables. It contains all of the SQL to create the tables and other database components, such as Indexes, Triggers and Views.
4. Create the core Migration code.
5. for each table, use the SQL but modified with changed table names, to create new tables.
6. for each table copy the data, if suitable using `INSERT INTO the_new_table SELECT * FROM the_original_table`

   1. see and read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
   2. if you have Foriegn Key constraints then parent tables MUST be created before the child tables throughout
   3. if you have new columns with the NOT NULL constraint then you will have to cater for this somehow.
7. After the data has all been copied you can rename the original tables user `ALTER TABLE RENAME TO another_name`
8. Rename the new tables so they have the correct name.
9. DROP the renamed (another_name) tables.

   1. note children will have to be dropped before parents.

- You could move 10 to replace 8 (but it is safer to rename and then delete)

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand something; if the module is irrelevant then why would I need to do migration when the database entities - and schemas - have not been changed, only moved to a different module?

Comment: @shadow if the case is that the `@Entities` have not changed (they are what the the schema is derived from) then you wouldn't need to do a migration (as long as the version number passed to the `@Database` is unchanged). You question referred to a migration on a number of occasions and hence the implication that one was needed.